# Display UserControl when working

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm in C# WPF.

My application contains a button used to load a file. It can take some seconds, so I created a circular progress bar like this :

[image]

But when I click on the load button, the progress bar is not displayed. It seems to be a problem with threading but I don't know how it properly works.

There is my code :
MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <local:CircularProgressBar Panel.ZIndex="1"
                               Visibility="Collapsed"
                               x:Name="progressBar"/>
    <Button Content="Load file"
            Command="{Binding LoadCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    (DataContext as MainViewModel).OnWork += MainWindow_OnWork;
}

private void MainWindow_OnWork(object sender, bool isStart)
{
    if (isStart)
        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    else
        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
protected RelayCommand loadCommand;
private String file;
public delegate void WorkEventHandler(object sender, bool isStart);
public event WorkEventHandler OnWork;

public ICommand LoadCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (loadCommand == null)
        {
            loadCommand = new RelayCommand(Load, CanLoad);
        }
        return loadCommand;
    }
}

private void Load()
{
    OpenFileDialog opnfldlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    opnfldlg.Multiselect = false;
    if (opnfldlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        if (OnWork != null)
            OnWork(this, true);

        // This is the part who takes a time
        Task<ReadResult> readTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadImage(opnfldlg.FileName));
        Task.WaitAll(readTask);
        ReadResult result= readTask.Result;

        if (OnWork != null)
            OnWork(this, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't bind the visibility of the CircularProgressBar  to a property of the viewmodel? `Visibility="{Binding Path=WaitingOnLoad,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">`

Comment: You must be right, it is my first use of this, it did it fast. So I just have to remove my event and replace `OnWork(this, true)` by `WaitingOnLoad = true` (same for false) ?

Comment: Yes, basically. As long as the WaitingOnLoad calls `PropertyChanged` in the property setter it will update the UI when it's set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task.WaitAll blocks the UI thread and a single thread cannot both wait and update the UI simultaneously. Try to await the Task asynchronously using async/await:

```
private async void Load()
{
    OpenFileDialog opnfldlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    opnfldlg.Multiselect = false;
    if (opnfldlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        if (OnWork != null)
            OnWork(this, true);

        // This is the part who takes a time
        ReadResult result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadImage(opnfldlg.FileName));

        if (OnWork != null)
            OnWork(this, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've try with that but I have an error "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'."
I 'm trying to debug but I'm not an expert in Task management.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the keyword async. It works thank you

Answer (score 1):

if you want to wait for the task then you can use below code.

```
Task.WaitAll(readTask).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

Above will force task to not wait for the result on UI thread.